# Javascript GMT string convert to Local Time

Tags: datepicker, localtime

```
 $(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepick({ 
        multiSelect: 999, 
        monthsToShow: 3,
        minDate: new Date(), 
                maxDate: '+1y', 
        showTrigger: '#calImg',
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',        
        onSelect: function(value) { 
            alert(value);
                } 
    });
 });
```

this code block returns a string like that `"Wed Jan 11 2012 12:00:00 GMT+0100"`. 
How can I convert that string like that `"2012-01-11 12:00:00"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this to covert to local time and get rid of GMT

```
function getLocalTimeFromGMT(sTime){ 
  var dte = new Date(sTime); 
  dte.setTime(dte.getTime() - dte.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);       
  document.write(dte.toLocaleString()); }
```

cf http://teck.in/indian-standard-time-and-gmt-from.html#ixzz1hNGiQAhg

Comment: I have to correct you by saying that when you go and toLocaleString() it converts the time back to the local time. You could just stop on the line before. Get it?